# (Uncertainty propagation) Should variance of log radiated energy be scale invariant?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, error-analysis

I need to propagate the error from the measure of the bolometric fluence $ S_\text{bolo}$ to the $\log_{10} $  of the isotropic-equivalent radiated energy $E_\text{iso}$  which is related to  $S_\text{bolo}$ by the formula
$$ E_\text{iso} = \frac{4 \pi d_\ell^2 S_\text{bolo}}{(1+z)}$$

but I am afraid I made some errors(x1) with the error(x2) propagation procedure because python raises me errors(x3 lol).

My measures of the bolometric fluence are in $10^{-5}\ \text{erg/cm}^2$ , while the redshift $z$ is assumed without error.

The luminosity distance instead is in Megaparsec since it is computed from the distance modulus as
$$ d_\ell= 10^{\dfrac{\mu-25}{5}}$$

Since I need $E_\text{iso}$ in erg, I first converted the measures of $S_\text{bolo}$ in erg/m$^2$ by dividing by 10 since $10^4/10^5 =10^{-1}$. I did the same for $\delta S_\text{bolo}$.

Regarding $d_\ell$, since python raises errors with such big numbers I  multiplied by $3.08567758128 \cdot 10^{22}$ in the theoretical formula so that I can avoid the issue once this term is eliminated. I did the same for $\delta d_\ell$.

$E_\text{iso}$ becomes

$$ E_\text{iso} = \frac{4 \pi}{(1+z)} \cdot d_\ell^2 \cdot 3.08567758128^2 \cdot 10^{44} \cdot S_\text{bolo} $$

while
$$ \log_{10}{(E_\text{iso})} = \log_{10}{\biggl( \frac{4 \pi}{(1+z)} \cdot d_\ell^2 \cdot 3.08567758128^2 \cdot S_{bolo} \biggr)} + 44$$

At this point, the error on $\log_{10}(E_\text{iso})$ gives me some problems. I think it should be
$$ \delta\log_{10}(E_{iso}) = \frac{1}{\ln{10}} \frac{\delta E_\text{iso}}{E_\text{iso}} $$

So that
$$ \delta\log_{10}(E_\text{iso}) =\frac{1}{\ln{10}}\sqrt{  \frac{(\frac{4 \pi}{(1+z)} \cdot d_\ell^2)^2 \delta S_b^2 +  (\frac{8 \pi}{(1+z)} \cdot d_\ell \cdot S_b)^2 \delta d_\ell^2} {(\frac{4 \pi}{(1+z)} \cdot d_\ell^2 \cdot S_b)^2}  }  = \frac{1}{\ln{10}}  \sqrt{\frac{(\delta S_b)^2}{S_b^2} + 4 \frac{\delta d_\ell^2}{d_\ell^2}    } $$

You can see that, due to the fraction, it ends being completely  independent from the rescaling. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: That's the basic property of logarithms. Are you supposed to be affected by the rescaling? Are you looking for $\delta E_\text{iso}$ or $\delta\text{lg}E_\text{iso}$? You have some leftover weird bits but you should be able to find them in the end.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent honestly, i asked because there seemed to be no error in the python code so i started questioning my calculations

Comment: If I were you, I would have worked in terms of $\mu$ instead of $d_\ell$ and also used this fractional form in the first place, so that there is no need to convert units at all. But I do not know if your propagation here is correct or not. I mean, it is not clear what particular thing you actually want.

Comment: I'm also confused. To me it seams as if your relation is $\tilde y = c \cdot y$, where $c$ is a constant, and $y$ is your measurement.